# socket io session map

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Hello on entering my backend I make a connection to my socket and send the player data + socket id

good, and then on receiving I add him in line

and perform a function that will fetch 2 players who have approximate points to form a match

and so I wanted to find a match send to the socket of the selected players

But I don't know how best to map session

I saw about express.socket-io

or save one of these socket's that connect in some way
for when I find a match
send my match to my selected socket's

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  //ADD PLAYER TO QUEUE
  socket.on('addPlayer-Queue', (result) => {
      const player = {
        id: result.id,
        name: result.name,
        mmr: result.mmr
      }
      const player = new Player(player,socketid )

  socket.emit('match', matches) 
  });

class Player {
    constructor(player,socketId) {
      this.id = player.id
      this.socketId = socketId
      this.name = player.name
      this.mmr = player.mmr
    }

  }
```

Here I get my player and create it, but I don't know how to get this player's socket.id and how to map in a session

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, here's a way to do it.

Everytime a players get added, I push them on an array and then call the function matchPlayersQueue that tries to match players based on their MMR (I haven't completed the code, but a way to do it, is either check the variance of MMRs or check their difference). If you follow this path, keep in mind that everytime a players disconnect that was on the queue array, you should remove the element.

Another way to do this is, set a timer that periodically calls the function matchPlayersQueue.

```js
let playersOnQueue = [];

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    //ADD PLAYER TO QUEUE
    socket.on("addPlayer-Queue", result => {
        const player = {
            id: result.id,
            name: result.name,
            mmr: result.mmr
        };
        const player = new Player(player, socketid);
        playersOnQueue.push(player);
        const matchedPlayers = matchPlayersQueue(playersOnQueue); // matchedPlayers will be an array of their sockets ids.
        // Do something with matchedPlayers, empty playersOnQueue if matchedPlayers.length doesn't equal to 0.
    });
});

function matchPlayersQueue(arr) {
    //We'll sort the array by mmr.
    arr.sort(function(firstPlayer, secondPlayer) {
        return firstPlayer.getMMR() - secondPlayer.getMMR();
    });
    if (arr.length >= 3) {
        //Trivial way to match 3 people, not checking for MMR.
        if (arr.length === 3) {
            const socketIDs = arr.map(function(player) {
                return player.getSocketID();
            });
            return socketIDs;
        } else {
            /*
                Here you can implement your own way of selecting players, maybe having a maximum MMR difference between players or comparing the overall variance of MMR.
            */
        }
    } else {
        //If there are fewer than 3 people.
        return [];
    }
}

class Player {
    /*
    Beware of this constructor, while this works, The way i'd would do it is each variable to their own attribute.
    */
    constructor(player, socketId) {
        this.id = player.id;
        this.socketId = socketId;
        this.name = player.name;
        this.mmr = player.mmr;
    }

    getMMR() {
        return this.mmr;
    }

    getSocketID() {
        return this.socketId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops bro is almost that but in my search
I wanted to get two players with a condition that have a difference of 5% to 10% of their mmr
I don't know how to do that
maybe with a .map?

Comment: @Felipe I've used Average Absolute Deviation ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation ) to match people, here's the working code: https://paste.ee/p/4jet9. It uses Array.filter to get "pivots" (the person in the center) and then push the other 2 people into an array. You may need to change maxAllowableDeviation to better suit your needs!. The code needs some changes for example, returning an array of array of players (something like: [["A", "B", "C"], ["E", "F", "G"]]